# Iterated arithmetic derivative

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-derivative

I found by accident the notion of *[arithmetic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative)*. It goes as follows: if $p$ is prime then $p' = 1$ and it follows the usual Leibniz rule
$$
(p q)' = p' q + p q'\quad\forall \;p,q \in\mathbb{N}\,.
$$
My question regards the iterated action of this derivative on natural numbers, that is, I want to study the behaviour of
$$
n^{(k)} \equiv n^{\overset{k}{\overbrace{\prime\ldots\prime}}}\,.
$$
This was inspired by a question in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iPmyl0vaas) (which is where I found out about this).

I am not a matematician so I don't have many tools to study this. So far I just did a table with Mathematica. It seems that powers of 2 tend to diverge to infinity (apart from $4$ which is a fixed point and $2$ which is prime). And I also observed that some numbers tend to infinity sharing the same trajectory, for example 
$$
160^{(5)} = 180^{(5)} = 4834\,,
$$
and diverge together from then onward. Another simple observation is the for any prime $p$, $(p^p)' = p^p$. So there are infinitely many fixed points.

Is there anything about this in the literature? Are there fixed points other than $p^p$? What is the rate of growth of $n^{(k)}$ when it doesn't reach zero? Is there a criterion to know in advance if a number is going to reach zero? Even a partial answer to any of these questions will be appreciated. I attach a log-log plot of the result of 30 iterations of the first $65536$ numbers. Red dots indicate powers of $2$.

[Log-Log plot of the first 65536 numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh9yM.jpg)

Comment: Relevant: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule

Comment: Let $f(n) = \sum_{p^k \| n} \frac{k}{p}$. Then $f(nm) = f(n)+f(m)$ is completely additive and you are looking at $D(n) = f(n) n$. You can extend to rationals with $f(n/m) = f(n)-f(m)$ and $D(x) = f(x) x$. For any completely additive function $g:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ then you can look at $x \mapsto g(x) x$. Those things are not linear so @JavaMan's comment doesn't apply.